# Schrödinger: Coherent states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, coherence

A coherent state is called

$\Psi_{{\alpha}} \left( x,t=0 \right)$

and is defined by:

$a_{{{\it \_}}}\Psi_{{\alpha}} \left( x \right) =\alpha\,\Psi_{{\alpha}} \left( x \right)  $

where $a_{{{\it \_}}}$ represent the lowering operator.

I must show that

$\Psi_{{\alpha}} \left( x,t=0 \right) ={{\rm e}^{-1/2\, \left(  \left| \alpha \right|
 \right) ^{2}}}\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {{\alpha}^{n}\psi_{{n}}
 \left( x \right) }{\sqrt {n!}}}$

is a coherent state.

How do I go about doing this? I understand that the above right-hand side is a normalization constant multiplied with a general solution to the time-independent Schrödinger equation, but I don't know how to show that it is a coherent state. I believe I am to use the eigenvalue, however this is as far as I am able to come at this hour. I would appreciate any help and hints.

Comment: First time users frequently forget to accept answers so I'll just let you know how this works. Once you find that an answer is satisfactory, click the check mark next to it. This gives the person who wrote the answer more rep and makes it easier for people browsing the questions list to see which questions need more attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, a coherent state is *defined* by the equation

$$a \Psi_{\alpha} = \alpha \Psi_{\alpha} \, .$$

Therefore, to check whether a particular expression is a coherent state, just act $a$ on it and see if you get the same thing back multiplied by a complex number.
Let's try it

$$
\begin{align}
a \Psi_{\alpha} &=
a \left[ e^{-|\alpha|^2/2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\alpha^n \psi_n}{\sqrt{n!}} \right] \\
&= e^{-|\alpha|^2/2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\alpha^n a \psi_n}{\sqrt{n!}} \\
&= e^{-|\alpha|^2/2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\alpha^n \sqrt{n}\psi_{n-1}}{\sqrt{n!}} \\
\text{factor out one power of }\alpha \qquad
&= \alpha e^{-|\alpha|^2/2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\alpha^{n-1} \psi_{n-1}}{\sqrt{(n-1)!}} \\
\text{let }m=n-1\qquad
&= \alpha \left[ e^{-|\alpha|^2/2} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{\alpha^m \psi_m}{\sqrt{m!}} \right] \, .
\end{align}
$$

If you look carefully at what you've got there, you'll see the resolution of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\Psi_\alpha = \sum_n c_n \psi_n$. This is always true because $\{\psi_n\}_{n=0,1,2,\ldots}$ is a Hilbertian basis.
Then uses the definition of $\Psi_\alpha$ and the one of $a$, **assuming that $a$ and the symbol of sum can be swapped**:
$$\sum_n \alpha  c_n \psi_n  = \alpha \Psi_\alpha = a \Psi_\alpha =  \sum_n c_n a\psi_n = \sum_n c_n \sqrt{n}\psi_{n-1}\:.$$
Comparing the first and the last sum,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \alpha c_n  \psi_n = \sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} c_{m+1} \sqrt{m+1}\psi_{m}$$

using the uniqueness of the coefficients of the decomposition of a vector along a Hilbert basis, you see that
$$\alpha c_n = c_{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}\:.$$
Assuming $c_0=\alpha$ (and this value can be fixed arbitrarily as it can be fixed up to a phase by the final normalization requirement, if $\alpha \neq 0$ otherwise we have the trivial vector) you have 
$$c_0=\alpha\:, \quad c_2 = \frac{\alpha^2}{\sqrt{2}}\:, \quad c_3 = \frac{\alpha^3}{\sqrt{3!}}\:, \ldots$$
In general
$$c_n = \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}}\:.$$
We have the candidate
$$\Psi_\alpha = c \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}} \psi_n\:.$$
By direct inspection, since the elements $\psi_n$ are orthonormal,
$$||\Psi_\alpha||^2 = |c|^2 \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(|\alpha|^2)^n}{n!}= |c|^2 e^{|\alpha|^2}\:.$$
The simplest choice for obtaining $||\Psi_\alpha||=1$ is $c = e^{-\frac{|\alpha|^2}{2}}$. Hence
$$\Psi_\alpha = e^{-\frac{|\alpha|^2}{2}} \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}} \psi_n\:.$$
Finally, on the mathematical side, one should check if
$$a\left(  \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}} \psi_n\right)=
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}} a\psi_n\tag{1}$$
This fact is not obvious because $a$ is **not** continuous. However it is a **closed** (actually closable) operator. It implies that (1) holds if both $$ \sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}} \psi_n$$
and
 $$\sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}} a\psi_n = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{(n-1)!}} \psi_{n-1}$$
**converge** in the Hilbert space to some vectors, as $N \to +\infty$. This is true because, for every $N=0,1,\ldots$
$$  \sum_{n=0}^{N} \left|\frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}}\right|^2 =\sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{|\alpha|^{2n}}{n!} \leq e^{|\alpha|^2} +\infty$$
and
$$  \sum_{n=1}^{N} \left|\frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{(n-1)!}}\right|^2 =\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |\alpha|^2\frac{|\alpha|^{2n}}{n!} \leq |\alpha|^2e^{|\alpha|^2}<+\infty\:.$$

Comment: $a$ is a linear operator.  Is there any reason to believe that it cannot be pushes through the summation sign, i.e. is there any reason to believe that $a$ and the symbol sum CANNOT be swapped?

Comment: If the sum is infinite and the operator is not bounded (i.e. continuos) as in this case, it is not necessaeily possible.

Comment: Sorry if I sound semantically challenged but surely it is possible to push $\hat a$ through the sum.  Whether or not the result $\hat a \,\Psi(x)$ remains in the original Hilbert space is a separate issue.  …or am I misunderstanding your point?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your point. If a linear operator $A$ with domain $D(A)$ in the Hilbert space ${\cal H}$ is not a closed nor a closable operator (differently from $a$ and $a^\dagger$), you my have $x_n \to 0$  and $A(x_n) {\not \to} 0$ for $n \to +\infty$. In particular, $x_n$ may be of the form $x_n = \sum_{j=1}^n y_n$... However,  this is basic linear functional analysis, I suggest you to have a look at a textbook on the subject. This is not the place where start a discussion on these things I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states.

It's written there that the coherent state is generated by the displacement operator $D(\alpha)$

$$|\alpha\rangle = D(\alpha)|0\rangle = \exp(\alpha a^\dagger - \alpha^*a)|0\rangle \, .$$

Now everything is simple. Expand $\exp(\alpha a^† - \alpha^*a)$ as you expand every exponential.

$$
\begin{align}
\exp(\alpha a^† - \alpha^*a) &=
1 + \alpha a^† - \alpha^* a + (1/2) (\alpha a^† - \alpha^*a)(\alpha a^† - \alpha^* a) \\
&+ (1/3!)(\alpha a^† - \alpha^* a)(\alpha a^† - \alpha^* a)(\alpha a^† - \alpha^* a) + \ldots
\end{align}
$$

and apply this operator to $|0\rangle$ and find the general term in the series.
Let me help you with a few first terms:

$$
\begin{align}
D(a)|0\rangle &= |0\rangle + \alpha|1\rangle + (\alpha/2) (\alpha a^† - \alpha^*a)|1\rangle \\
&+ (\alpha/3!)(\alpha a^† - \alpha^* a)(\alpha a^† - \alpha^*a)|1\rangle + \ldots\\
&= |0\rangle + \alpha|1\rangle + (\alpha^2 \sqrt{2}|2\rangle - \alpha α^*|0\rangle)/2 \\
&+ (\alpha/3!)(\alpha a^† - a \alpha^* a)(\alpha^2 \sqrt{2}|2\rangle - \alpha \alpha^*|0\rangle) + \ldots
\end{align}
$$

Use whenever needed the expressions of the raising and lowering operators on Fock states $|n\rangle$, i.e. $a|n\rangle = \sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle$, and $a^†|n\rangle = \sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle$, and also the fact that $a|0\rangle = 0$.

After obtaining the series, and, most important, the general term, you can normalize the series by using the Poisson distribution norm.

Try your hand!

Good luck !

Comment: Hi Sofia. It seems you type a lot of your equations using direct input of Greek letters. Nothing wrong with that. However, if you use TeX formatting you can make all those equations look really nice. I will edit your answer. You can look at how I did the TeX :)

Comment: @DanielSank: Hi Daniel, good day! That's true and annoying. Ruslan was so kind to indicate a place where I can find the instructions for TeX. He said "you can find them "here" ". I went into "here", but at that time I was busy and didn't have time. Now I don't know anymore where is that "here". Can you tell me the address of "here"?

Comment: Annoyingly, I can't find a reference for how TeX works on this site. If you already know the basics of TeX, just put $ symbols surrounding anything you want rendered as TeX. If you don't already know TeX, your best option is to do a Google search for "TeX tutorial". This will be really useful in your research career too.

Comment: The other thing you can do is click `edit` on your answer here to see how I did the TeX. You can do this on any answer where you see nice equations to see an example of how TeX works.

Comment: @DanielSank: I will try, but now I want to post a better proof (induction) of the formula that the fellow asked. After that I'll try the edit as you say.

Comment: Wikipedia's manual for math typesetting is very useful, because you can just glance over at what you want to produce, and copy the TeX next to it.

http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula

Comment: @lionelbrits: thank you Lionel. But now I want to finish the help to the fellow, and after that I'll follow the advices.

Comment: Hey, Sofia, this is the link you want regarding Tex: http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation. Hope it helps.

Comment: @DanielSank: are you in some chat-room? I wanted to help the fellow with a proof that I think is better than those posted by both of us. But I got stuck with something stupid, and lost a lot of time. The most convincing proof for showing someone how this formula appears, is to begin from the generator of the coherent state. Then, developing the operator in Taylor series and applying to |0>, one has to get the formula, up to the normalization factor. The latter is easily obtained from the norm of the Poisson distribution. But I got stuck with something stupid. If you can help it would be good.